# Which technologies could be useful for designing LabVIEW-like web front-ends?

Tags: web-development, framework, vector-graphics, svg

Typical LabVIEW front panels ([1](http://forums.ni.com/attachments/ni/170/322557/1/Overview_Manual.PNG), [2](http://www.originalcode.com/images/LRDSFrontPanel.jpg)) are not something that is easy to explicitly construct using the DOM.

I am looking for a combination of frameworks/libraries/approaches that would allow drawing a schematic of a system and registering events etc. for the different elements in the schematic.

One option I'm thinking of is an [SVG](http://snapsvg.io/) drawing but I do not know if that is good practice.

Comment: Sooner or later you would probably need displays or panels showing graphs or waveforms. These need to get redrawn quickly. Thus you need cutting-edge asyncronous programming techniques available in the browser, to have a responsive GUI and also near-real time updaets over longer time periods. - All this implies that you need to answer the question early on: how backward compatible must it be? Do you need to support IE, ...?

Comment: @knb doesn't need to be backwards compatible: user will use whatever browser I tell them

Comment: Depending on your performance requirements (graph update freq, data density, etc...) you might also look using C/C++ and building using [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/).